# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression": how to write sql correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

**How do I successfully write this query?**

> Extract the First and Last Name, and GPA of each student who qualifies
>   for the Dean’s List. Sort by GPA, then Last Name, then First Name (1
>   sort). A GPA of 3.25 is required to make the Dean’s List.

Below is the query that I wrote and I keep getting the error message,

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression":***

```
Select Students.[First Name], Students.[Last Name],GPA.[Current GPA]
FROM Students INNER JOIN GPA ON Students.ID = GPA.ID
WHERE (((GPA.[Current GPA])>3.24))
ORDER BY GPA.[Current GPA], Students.[Last Name], Students.[First Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the `data types` of the values in the comparisons in your query:

1. Check that the data type of `Students.ID` and `GPA.ID` are the same
2. Check that the data type of `GPA.[Current GPA])` is a numeric type so it can be compared with 3.24

Try setting the data types as follows:

For `Student.Id` and `GPA.Id` set:

- data type: Number
- Field Size: Long Integer
- Format:(blank)
- Decimal places: auto.

  And set `GPA.[Current GPA]` to:
- data type: Number
- Field Size: double
- Format:(blank)
- Decimal places: 3

Comment: I changed Students.ID and GPA.ID to Number, General Number, with 3 decimal places, but now my table only shows rounded #'s for the gpa's. (3 instead of 3.79, 2 instead of 2.25)  how do I correct that?

Comment: What are the data types for Students.Id, GPA.Id and GPA.CurrentGPA?

Comment: Student ID : "Number", Field size "double" Format "general Number" Decimal places auto"      

Gurrent GPA: "Number" Field size "decimal" Format "general Number" Decimal places "auto"

GPA  ID "Number" Field size "double" Formant "general Number" Decimal places "auto"

Comment: And `GPA.Current GPA`? Why are you telling me information for just one column?

Comment: Anyway you need to set `Student.Id` and `GPA.Id` to data type: Number/ Field Size: Long Integer/ Format:(blank)/Decimal places auto.    An set `GPA.[Current GPA]` to data type: Number/Field Size: double/ Format: (blank)/ Decimal places: 3. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: GPA.Current GPA is "Number" Field size "decimal" Format "general Number" Decimal places "auto"

Comment: @umyesitsme I've modified my original answer with the column names that should work.

Comment: I've modified the data according to your answer and suggestions, but the Current GPA is still showing as a round number.

Comment: There's no reason for it to not work. I can only help more if you can upload the db or the relevant part of it somewhere I can access it